# Nokogiri lose my attribute's value named 'multiple'

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Here's the code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<!DOCTYPE html><html><input multiple='false' id='test' some='2'/><div multiple='false'></div></html>")

puts doc.errors

doc.css("input").each do |el|
    puts el.attributes['multiple']
end

puts doc.to_html
```

And here's the output:

```
false
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<input multiple id="test" some="2"><div multiple></div>
</body></html>
[Finished in 2.0s]
```

Where are the two ='false' ??

**EDIT**

PLus, is there a way to turn down the default correction?? (use to_xhtml can keep the ='false' but and CDATA into script tag)

In my option, to_xhtml seems working more strictly, why to_xhtml keep the multiple='false' instead??

**EDIT2**

Here's my temporary workaround: **gsub(/multiple=/, 'blahhhhh')** before parsing and **gsub(/blahhhhh/, 'multiple=')** back after parsing

Comment: `Where are the two 'false's??`? There is only one `"false"` and one `"true"`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `to_html` with `to_xhtml` and you will get `multiple` attributes values back again.

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<!DOCTYPE html><html><input multiple='false' id='test' some='2'/><div multiple='true'></div></html>")
puts doc.to_xhtml
```

will output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <input multiple="false" id="test" some="2" />
    <div multiple="true"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update** This happens because in HTML the `multiple` attribute (and other attributes such `disabled` or `selected`) doesn't require to have a value so Nokogiri strips it to clean up the output code.

**Update 2**

> why to_xhtml keep the multiple='false' instead?

Because XHTML don't let to omit the value of the attributes, so Nokogiri keeps them.

The best thing you can do, I think, is to feed Nokogiri with proper HTML code in the first place, i.e. omit the `multiple` attribute entirely instead of write `multiple="false"`.

Comment: i also tested out that to_xhtml works, but xhtml brings more problems with HTML5, still debugging

Comment: @rhapsodyn If you are using HTML5 keep in mind that `multiple`, `multiple="true"` and `multiple="false"` are all equivalent.

Comment: `Browsers ignore the value of such attributes.` Nokogiri isn't a browser, it's a parser, and it has a good idea of what the HTML spec says markup should look like, so it doesn't display the `="false"` or `="true"` when you ask for HTML output using `to_html`. It's doing some clean-up to generate proper HTML.